# In eclipse my web content folder of my project is showing a red cross how to resolve it?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, eclipse-plugin

[Errors in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O6YD.png)
Recently I updated java on my laptop. After that, a red cross is there on my web content folder of my project in Eclipse IDE. The web content folder contains jsp files.
 How to resolve this issue?

under **JSP problem** :

Class cannot be resolved
ClassNotFoundException cannot be resolved to a type
Connection cannot be resolved to a type
DriverManager cannot be resolved
Exception cannot be resolved to a type
HttpSession cannot be resolved to a type
Integer cannot be resolved
ResultSet cannot be resolved to a type
Statement cannot be resolved to a type
String cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Eclipse is probably looking for the jre in your previous java installation directory, you have to point it to the newly updated one. https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-change-java-version

Comment: Can you read what the markers or errors says ?

Comment: Can you *show* us, and check what Errors the Problems View shows for the project?

Comment: added error screenshot and errors under JSP problem

Comment: Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences, and within that, Java -> Installed JREs;
Change the Java Version of Our Project: Project properties and then to the Java Build Path.